# How to get the org_id from a webhook?

Tags: podio

When a Webhook is triggered, is there a way to get the `org_id` from which it was fired? (Aside from climbing up the triggered item)

The only solution I found so far is:

1. `PodioItem::get($item_id);` to get the  space_id
2. `PodioSpace::get($space_id);` to get the full
3. `PodioOrganization::get_for_url($attributes = array());` I get the `org_id`.

Answer (score 1):

See the "Bundling responses using fields parameter" section at the very bottom of https://developers.podio.com/index/api on how you can use the `fields` query parameter to include more data. There's even an example that goes almost all the way for you (it walks up to the space level, but you can just tack the org onto it):

```
/item/{item_id}?fields=app.view(full).fields(space.view(full))
```

For podio-php you can do:

```
$item = PodioItem::get($item_id, array('fields' => "app.view(full).fields(space.view(full))"));
```

Comment: Do I change `{item_id}` by the actual item_id like this? `{1112223333}`. I tried without the `fields` paramater, with it like your exemple and finally the same thing but with the replaced id. It all returned the same thing, the item by itself. Is it a good practice to put coding in the comment or I should edit my question with the attempts?

Comment: My second example was a complete copy/paste error, should be better now

Comment: It doesn't seem to work still. Here's the code I'm trying: http://oi61.tinypic.com/24erel3.jpg
Both output files are the very same size and do not explicitely provide any org_id (through a space object).

Answer (score 0):

Use `PodioItem::filter` instead of `PodioItem::get`, I'm pretty sure that you'll have the expected results, so try this:
`$item = PodioItem::filter($item_id, array('filters' => "app.view(full).fields(space.view(full))"));`

Hope it helps!